# Calling SSL-secured webservice from Oozie job

Tags: web-services, hadoop, ssl, oozie

I am trying to run an oozie job that invokes a SSL-secured webservice. I have a couple of questions:

1. Where to store keystore file? Shall it be saved to each working node? Or does it need to be in HDFS so Oozie job can access?
2. How shall I pass the the password to oozie other than store it in workflow.xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you planning to invoke the web service from Oozie? Documentation i read does not recommend using Oozie for off cluster jobs/ services.